# Return current on Adafruit GPS

Tags: rf, gps

This might have a dumb answer, but here goes...

This is a picture of the u.fl connector on the Adafruit ultimate GPS.

[image]

With RF lines, I know you want the shortest return path.  So why did they put the ground vias so far away?  Wouldn't it be better to put the vias in the pad?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via-in-pad costs more to do it right.

You can't just drop a via in a pad and expect it to solder properly in production without taking precautions, since the solder paste which should be on the pad tends to get sucked down into the via hole during reflow instead of staying on the pad where it belongs.

You can have the via hole filled, either with a copper plug or with something else which is then plated over to produce a nice solid flat pad.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, thanks...  Is there any reason the vias weren't put closer, or is that considered close enough?

Comment: meh ... I would've tried to put them a bit closer if I were doing the layout, but clearly they're selling it & it works (well enough anyway)...